# can someone explain what is the meaning of this code under the elbow meshing in k-means

Tags: python, cluster-analysis, k-means

Instantiate the clustering model and visualizer

```
model = KMeans(random_state = 42)

visualizer = KElbowVisualizer(model, k=(2,10))
```

Fit the data to the visualizer

```
visualizer.fit(df_final.values)
```

Finalize and render the figure

```
visualizer.show()
```

Comment: can you be a bit more specific?

Answer (score 0):

**K-means** is an unsupervised learning, the number of clusters in the technique is called K and user has to define this number.

Now,

```
visualizer = KElbowVisualizer(model, k=(2,10))
```

In the above line of code, we are defining a range for the number of K to pass to the model in a range of **2-9** and select **K** where an elbow is formed which basically means that where ever the value of K and sum of squared errors is less, that K is selected.

Also this elbow method works well only when the data is very clustered.

Later,

```
visualizer.fit(df_final.values)
```

The above line is going to fit the data on the visualizer and plot different values on the figure with different K on x-axis and distortion score on y-axis.

**Example code:**(https://www.scikit-yb.org/en/latest/api/cluster/elbow.html)

```
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
from sklearn.datasets import make_blobs

from yellowbrick.cluster import KElbowVisualizer

# Generate synthetic dataset with 8 random clusters
X, y = make_blobs(n_samples=1000, n_features=12, centers=8, random_state=42)

# Instantiate the clustering model and visualizer
model = KMeans()
visualizer = KElbowVisualizer(model, k=(4,12),)

visualizer.fit(X)        # Fit the data to the visualizer
visualizer.draw()
```

**Output**:

[image]

Comment: can you tell what is that dot line ???? is that need to connect with elbow diagrame to find optimum number of clusters??

Comment: thank you soo much !!! and i have another doubt. why are we using 42 as random state?? i saw all sample codes are using 42

Comment: The reason for number 42 is answered here : https://www.quora.com/Why-do-we-choose-random-state-as-42-very-often-during-training-a-machine-learning-model